# What do I do with the Boots of Introspection?

Tags: candy-box-2

What do I do with the Boots Of Introspection? When I have them equipped, I can't walk. Is there something else I can use them for?

Answer (score 5):

I found one way of using it: go to forest with boots of introspection on your feet, you won't move, but the animals keep coming at you, you get a lot of candies by killing them...and this is an endless process that means you can farm tons of candies this way.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the Wiki](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Boots_of_Introspection), you obtain these boots from defeating yourself, and their sole purpose is to prevent you from moving.  The description:

> Take the time to breathe and calm down. If you wear these boots, you will never move as long as you touch the ground.

It sounds like its a gag item, especially when one considers the definition of Introspection.

> Introspection: the examination or observation of one's own mental and emotional processes.

Answer (score 1):

They are good for fighting the monkey wizard so you can stand still and use magic if you have any. If you walk towards him he will jump over you, but you can move with a pogo stick.